# onOpen trigger combobox update

Tags: google-apps-script

Scenario 
Form 1: Add Customer Information and save in mySQL db.

Form 2: Add Invoice and select customer added from Form 1. Need to use Combobox to select Customer.

Need a suggestion or code snippet for same.

Note: Based on working with Google Forms, it appears I cannot update Combobox in Form View.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of populating a drop down Google Form List with the names of sheets in a spreadsheet.  You could just as easily loop through a column of data containing customer names and do the same thing.

**The Code:**

```
function editingASimpleForm()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bNqs3YeALOsIzMqnTg6SfK-7mHNcPZQ0ZuC81ee3LRU')
  var allShts=ss.getSheets();
  var excShts=['Form Responses 4'];
  var incShts=[];
  var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var s=Utilities.formatString('Form name is <strong>%s</strong> and id is <strong>%s</strong>', form.getTitle(),form.getId());
  var allItems=form.getItems();
  /*
  for(var i=0;i<allItems.length;i++)
  {
    s+=Utilities.formatString('<br />Title: <strong>%s</strong> Type <strong>%s</strong> Id: <strong>%s</strong> Index: <strong>%s</strong>', allItems[i].getTitle(),allItems[i].getType(),allItems[i].getId(),allItems[i].getIndex())
  }
  */
  for(var i=0;i<allItems.length;i++)
  {
    var itm=allItems[i];
    if(itm.getId()=='405225448')//I got this id from the above commented out code which outputs title,type,id and index
    {
      var li0=itm;
    }
  }
  for(var i=0;i<allShts.length;i++)//this loop gets the non excluded sheet names into an array
  {
    if(excShts.indexOf(allShts[i].getName())==-1)
    {
      incShts.push(allShts[i].getName());
    }
  }
  li0.asListItem().setChoiceValues(incShts);//This populates the list
  /*
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(1200).setHeight(450);
  FormApp.getUi().showModalDialog(ui, 'Form Editing');
  */
}
```

I hope this helps.  If I misinterpreted the questions let me know.